# How can I modify each of the values in array?

Tags: scala

I would like to change all values in a multidimensional array but I'm receiving the "reassignment to val" error.

Scala code:

```
var cal = Array.ofDim[Double](300, 10000000);
cal.foreach(x => {
    x.foreach({o => o = 5.1} //here it'll be more complicated code 
)});
```

Does any body knows how to reassign the values in Array ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is in-place modification bulk operation is `transform` on [mutable sequences](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Seq).

```
for (y <- 0 until cal.length) {
  cal(y).transform(x => 5.1)
}
```

You can also do:

```
for (y <- 0 until cal.length) {
  val row = cal(y)
  for (x <- 0 until row.length) {
    row(x) = 5.1
  }
}
```

Comment: Where `n` is the size of `cal`, and `m` is the size of each row, and comma is multiplication? Of course.

Comment: Thanks, If I need to use index of transform array should I use zipWithIndex.transform ?

Comment: No, that would create a new array of pairs of elements and their indices - `Array[(T, Int)]`. Even worse, that intermediate array would then be updated. Instead, you should use the nested for loops over ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is the best way but it works:

```
  val cal = Array.ofDim[Double](300, 10000000) 
  (0 until cal.length).foreach(rowIndex => {
     val row = cal(rowIndex)
     (0 until row.length).foreach(colIndex => {
        row(colIndex) = 5.1 //here it'll be more complicated code
     })
  })
```

The reason for the error you got is that you are trying to assign a value to the immutable function parameter `o` in `o => o = 5.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using `var` you can simply

```
var cal = Array.ofDim[Double](300, 10000000);
cal = cal.map{
  a=>a.map{
    o=> 1.5 \\complex calculations 
  }
}
```

**NB:** This is not idiomatic scala or even functional, but it works.